# Calculate previous date present in data

Tags: sql, oracle

Given below is my dataset where I need to calculate previous transaction date column

```
Client  Account No  Trade Date  Amount  Previous Transaction Date
A        1          1/1/2016    10        -
A        2          1/2/2015    20        -
A        3          1/3/2015    30        -
A        1          1/4/2017    40        1/1/2016
A        2          1/5/2017    50        1/2/2015
B        1          1/6/2017    60        -
A        2          1/7/2017    70        1/5/2017
```

How can I get it done in most efficient manner as i have huge data. needs to be done in Oracle SQl

Comment: previous date for client?account? explain that as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is a direct application of `lag` window function.

```
select t.*
,lag(trade_date) over(partition by client,account_no order by trade_date) as prev_txn_date
from tbl t
```

Comment: HOw does lead function works when there are entries of same dates as shown in example added above. I have also added wrong answer given by lead function

Comment: `lead` gets you data from the *next* row. i would suggest you try it and observe the results with both lead and lag to better understand how they work.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala - besides the confusion between `lead()` and `lag()`, the OP is asking a legitimate question. Suppose there are multiple rows for the same client and account, and with the same date. How will `lag()` work in that case? Of course, the OP must explain what result is *needed* in that case; another poster asked exactly the same question, where that other poster said in that case the most recent **different** date is needed, which will not be obtained without some additional modification of `lag()`. We can probably assume both posters are working on the same homework.

Answer (score 0):

other way is create a function and use it in your query, see sample code below,

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_previous_transaction_date (p_client VARCHAR2, p_account_no VARCHAR2, p_trade_date DATE) RETURN DATE
IS
    v_prev_date DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(trade_date)
      INTO v_prev_date
      FROM your_table
     WHERE client = p_client
       AND account_no = p_account_no
       AND trade_date < p_trade_date;
    RETURN v_prev_date;
END;
/

SELECT client, account_no, trade_date, amount, get_previous_transaction_date(client, account_no, trade_date)
  FROM your_table;
```